# how do I get partial output of cgi script (piece by piece)

Tags: firefox, output-buffering

Given the following little cgi-script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""

echo '<html>'
echo '<head>'
echo '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">'
echo '</head>'
echo '<body>'
if [ $QUERY_STRING="yes" ]; then
    echo "before"
    sleep 5
    echo "after"
fi
echo '</body>'
echo '</html>'
```

How can I manage to get the output "before" first, then the delay of 5 sec, then the output "after" in this order in the browser?

Comment: How does that behave for now? IMHO bash honor the "sleep" but your browser postpone display until the `</body>` tag. Have you tried to wrap "before" and "after" in a block display element (`<p>` as an example) .

Comment: Tags don't make a difference. I tried <p> and <pre>. "Sleep" here is just a placeholder for some time consuming operation. This postponing the output is exactly what I want to get rid off.

Comment: _"This postponing the output is exactly what I want to get rid off."_ It was only speculation. Are you _sure_ the _browser_ "postpone" the display? Maybe the output stream is simply buffered somewhere? Maybe by your web-server? You definitively have to identify clearly where the output is "blocked" and to edit your question to provide the necessary bits of information.

Comment: The source of the postponing is not known to me. What settings can I try to figure out whether it is the configuration of apache2 in my case or the browser (I tried Safari and IE, both behave the same).

Comment: _"The source of the postponing is not known to me"_ If I were you, I would have already tried to capture the stream with [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) or any other network analyzer. That will show you the "timing" of the data packets -- so you would see if there is or no the expected delay in the stream. Maybe there is a more basic tool to do that? I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

Given the various info you gave in your comments, there is a decent possibility the problem was caused by some output buffering at Apache level.

To "stream" you CGI output, you absolutely need to disable [mod_deflate](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_deflate.html) (at least for the directory containing your CGI). If you use a `.htaccess` for your config, something *like* that *might* work:

```
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .sh
SetEnv no-gzip dont-vary
```

---

<sup>I've re-tagged your question as [apache](/questions/tagged/apache) in the hope someone might provide better info. If it is confirmed the issue is with the Apache configuration, you would probably have better luck asking on http://serverfault.com though.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your hints. Unfortunately they did not solve the problem. Strange enough trying 10 times once it behaved like exprected. It is something about buffering, I think too. Additionally the original example (the one above is a broken down extract) behaves differently on different brwosers. It works like expected on Safari and IE, it does not on Firefox and Opera

Comment: Update: it is not an apache problem. "netcat" shows that the response is sent piece by piece by Apache.  IE shows delayed output, Safari and Firefox do not. It is browser specific.

Comment: Thank you @AlexanderStippler for this feedback. I let my answer for future reference only. If this is browser specific, you will have to find a "trick" that works cross-browser. Maybe some clever JavaScript ? Anyway, this is now a much more difficult issue ! You should definitively update your question with those various pieces of info in order to attract answerers proficient in that domain.